# How to write data from multiple xml tags into multiple columns in csv?

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to take data from API call that returns XML object and parse few data points into a csv file with each object in its own column.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<YourMembership_Response>
<Items>
<Item>
<ItemID></ItemID>
<ID>92304823A-2932</ID>
<WebsiteID>0987</WebsiteID>
<NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<MiddleName></MiddleName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
<Suffix></Suffix>
<Nickname></Nickname>
<EmployerName>abc company</EmployerName>
<WorkTitle>manager</WorkTitle>
<Date>3/14/2013 2:12:39 PM</Date>
<Description>Removed from group by Administration.</Description>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemID></ItemID>
<ID>92304823A-2932</ID>
<WebsiteID>0987</WebsiteID>
<NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<MiddleName></MiddleName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
<Suffix></Suffix>
<Nickname></Nickname>
<EmployerName>abc company</EmployerName>
<WorkTitle>manager</WorkTitle>
<Date>3/14/2013 2:12:39 PM</Date>
<Description>Removed from group by Administration.</Description>
</Item>
```

I have written this code to write just IDs into CSV, which works fine.

```
with open("output1.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for node in tree.findall('.//ID'):
        writer.writerow([node.text])
```

Now when I attempting to write multiple data points into csv, the machine is simply appending the data points into one column. This the code here I have been attempting with:

```
with open("test1.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for node in tree.findall('.//ID'):
        writer.writerow([node.text])
    for node in tree.findall('.//FirstName'):
        writer.writerow([node.text])
    for node in tree.findall('.//LastName'):
        writer.writerow([node.text])
```

I need the data to look like this in the csv with other data points of choosing later on, what am I doing wrong?:

```
ID                    FirstName     LastName
92304823A-2932         John           Smith
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How big is the input xml?

Comment: I dont have an answer for the input size, but there are roughly 15000 members I have to do this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, in essence, how to collect the data.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree.parse('api.xml')
>>> tree.findall('.//Item')
[<Element 'Item' at 0x0000000006679EA8>, <Element 'Item' at 0x0000000006681318>]
>>> for item in tree.findall('.//Item'):
...     item.find('ID').text, item.find('FirstName').text, item.find('LastName').text
... 
('92304823A-2932', 'John', 'Smith')
('92304823A-2932', 'John', 'Smith')
```

In contrast, when you use a construct like `tree.findall('.//ID')` you are asking the xpath engine to start with `tree` (that's the '.' part) and look down through the branches for all occurences of 'ID' *at once*. This means that, in you sample xml code you will get a *set* of two IDs which won't even necessarily be in the original order. What you need to do is, first find all of the `Item` entries, then find the three corresponding data pieces of interest for that `Item`.

Addendum:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('api.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
...     fieldnames = ['ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName']
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
...     writer.writeheader()
...     for item in tree.findall('.//Item'):
...         writer.writerow({
...             'ID': item.find('ID').text,
...             'FirstName': item.find('FirstName').text,
...             'LastName': item.find('LastName').text})
```

Resulting output file:

```
ID,FirstName,LastName
92304823A-2932,John,Smith
92304823A-2932,John,Smith
```